# Element does not show truly

Tags: html, css

In my page when i add element all gone below menu but i want show them in body, for example i add a panel in my page but it gone below menu, how can i fix it?

there is my code :

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header"> ... </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> ... </ul>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
                                 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                             <li><a style="font-size: 18px;" href="#"><span style="font-size: 12px; background-color: #cc2200;" class="badge">358</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span></a></li>
                              ....
                     </ul>
                 </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                         <div class="panel-body">hello</div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://sscce.org and http://jsfiddle.net required.

Comment: @Samuel Liew: i use bootstrap libraries and code of my page just this.

Comment: How do you add an element?

Comment: @BlackSheep: i add a panel but it gone below menu, it is in my code.

Comment: Your question as it is doesn't make any sense, what _"code"_ are you talking about? Is it JavaScript? Why don't you post it?

Comment: i just have a html page that i add a menu and a panel in it , menu does not have problem but when i add panel it is gone below menu, but i want it will show in body.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @BlackSheep: this is the  link: http://jsfiddle.net/rgJPW/

Comment: That's because you are using `.navbar-fixed-top` class in your html, see http://jsfiddle.net/rgJPW/1/

Comment: @BlackSheep:  i want that menu show like fixed top, how can i make it?

Comment: Well, one option is using `margin-top` property. http://jsfiddle.net/rgJPW/2/

Comment: and when i add a popover in panel again i have problem

Comment: @BlackSheep: this is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/rgJPW/3/

Comment: What kind of problem? I can see a `z-index` problem and why the `popover` has such inline styles? http://jsfiddle.net/rgJPW/5/

Comment: @blackSheep: please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/rgJPW/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45049/discussion-between-blacksheep-and-elham-gdz)